# Views to show all child terms without showing parent

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Vocabulary has 5 parents, each containing 10 child.

Through views I want to display all child terms in a block, but to hide/skip showing parent terms in result.

Creating view that displays both parents and child was easy, but this I cant figure out.

Comment: you mean you want only all the 50 children being displayed?

Comment: Yes, only children terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a relationship with your parent term. After that you can set a filter with your parent term and filter all terms, which have a parent term id (parent taxonomy term: term id(not null)).